# Help with Music Rhythm Game (Cocos2D)

Tags: cocos2d, music

I'm basically new to the whole idea of Cocos2d.. i am aware of CocosDhension.. however, i still cant get the idea of working around it..

My idea, i would like to try to create something like "Tap Tap" .. a simple game.. where music is played and notes fall till the points where u have to hit the notes.

Question: where do i start from here as i have no idea how to go around this.. i have a basic logic in my head whereby i analyze the beat of the music and drop the notes accordingly?

can someone please give me a head up about this?

help is much appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: [Synthesia](http://synthesiagame.com/) does this using standard midi files

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of game you have many possibilities to do. It depends what you really want. If you know the musics in advance (already packaged into your application) the most simple is to create your own file format with its own structure. Then you can join each music file with the description file which contains the time of each beats.

Otherwise if you want analyze the sound in live, I don't think CocosDenshion is a good choice. You should consider to use the [Apple Audio Unit framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). It is best way to have a low level and performant audio analyzer. However it is hard to use.

I hope it should help you, but I can't given you more details about the implementation.